# How can i make dark mode for nav bar with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i m trying to implement dark mode to my website project, i did it for the body part with js, but i can't do it for navigation bar using 'navbar' class. Here is my js codes:

```
function darkMode() {
var element = document.body;
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
```

As you can see it's just for the body element. When i try to create variable for navbar it doesn't work.

```
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar_left">
        <a href="index.php">
            <img src="img/logo_transparent.png">
        </a>
    </div>

    <form class="navbar_mid" action="./action_page.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
        <button id="searchbutton" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
    <div class="navbar_right">
        <?php echo $multipleBtn; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my navbar codes. If i can write a correct js codes i can handle the css codes. Can you help me?

UPDATE

I tried body.dark-mode #navbar {background color:#ddd;} and it actually worked. But only for my index.php file as you can see below:

[image]

but my other php file it looks like this:

[image]

I really checked the codes twice, css 's files are the same for both pages and implemented for both. Could you help me with this problem?

Comment: It would be much simpler to only toggle the class on the body and then target all of your CSS based on that. E.g. `body.dark-mode #navbar { background-color: #333333; }`

Comment: use `navbar.classList.toggle` instead of `element.classList.toogle`. youd defined `element` as variable for the body.

Comment: Sorry, I removed my previous answer. However, if it did not work, there might be something wrong with the CSS, can you post the dark-mode part for the navbar?